# Alternative for Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jackson, taglib

I am looking for a taglib to be used with or instead of Jackson `ObjectMapper`. I am working on upgrading our website, and we do not allow inline code blocks in our JSP files. So therefor I need to find some tag library that can solve my problems.

```
<jsp:useBean id="mapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"  />
<%=mapper.writeValueAsString(pageContext.getAttribute("result"))%>
```

But I can not convert this to something like this:

```
 <c:out value="${mapper.writeValueAsString(pageContext.getAttribute('result'))}"></c:out>
```

This throws exception:

> The function writeValueAsString must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom JSTL function:

- it has to be a static method
- make a .tl that defines the function:

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://foo.com/tags</uri>

    <function>
        <name>getJSON</name>
        <function-class>com.....ObjectMapper</function-class>
        <function-signature>String writeValueAsString(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then you can use it with `f:getJSON(..)`

But generally, it might not be right to do this in the JSP - precompute it in the controller/servlet, and add it as model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, by implementing the functionality in a .tag file in the WEB-INF folder, where we allow inline coding. Not exactly the best solution, but it works.